# How to grant permission to the TelephoneManager.class to read a file in Android-X86

Tags: android, permissions, android-x86

I've built a custom AndroidX86 build for QA purposes  where the `TelephonyManager.class` is reading the content of a file located in **/storage/emulated/0/MY_DIR**. The problem is when attempting to read from file a `"Permission Denied"` error occurs. Can anyone please tell me how can I grant permission to the `TelephonyManager.class` to read a file?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

in Activity

```
 if (!checkPermission()) {
        requestPermission();
    } else {
        // you have access to the phone state continue your work
    }  

 public boolean checkPermission(String type) {

   int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

       return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

}

public void requestPermission(String type) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin. Thank you for your answer! Maybe I didn't made myself understood but I created a custom build and I'm trying to read the file from the TelephonyManager.class.